# how to make exostar api request in aws linux 2023 with ceritifica ？

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssl, curl, openssl

We need to call the exostar api, and this institution's api is https and requires certificate verification. So he asked us to generate a private key and a csr file
The command is as follows:

```
openssl req -out csr_to_**.txt -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 -subj "/C=**/ST=**/L=**/O=** **/OU=**/**=**"
```

Two files are generated

csr_to_**.txt
privkey.pem

After we send csr_to_**.txt to the organization, it gives us a p7b file.

Now the question:

How do we use this p7b certificate and curl to make api requests?

I try make api call with curl ,but not successsful yet

Comment: `man curl` and search for `cert`. There is a lot to learn about using certificates with curl. (I don't know the answer and don't have time to figure it out). Good luck.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/417140/convert-from-p7b-to-pem-via-openssl and https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/tls/clientcert and